# "Can not find the event ID matching navigation view for action '{1}' with the result '{2}'"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, navigation

I made a form with inputText and put a tag to view messages ( `<p:messages closable="true" />` ). A button with the action associated with either method returns a message. The problem is that whenever I click on the button first get the following message:

> Can not find the event ID matching navigation view ' /pages/updatedonante.xhtml ' for action {1} ' with the result ' {2}'.

I watched several tutorials but I fail to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem is it's unable to find the view to which it need to navigate.
Your method is returning some message, please ensure that message is appropriately mapped to some .xhtml page like(Explicit navigation):-

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/faces/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>METHOD_MESSAGE</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/faces/update.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

or message returned from the method should be same as some .xhtml page name where you want to navigate (Implicit navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! That was very helpful . The problem was that he was calling a method from

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.method()}" />
```

But actually my method should return , as well you indicated me , the .xhtml page that displays the message. I could fix just returning

```
return "/pages/updatedonante.xhtml";
```

in my method. Thanks again!